# I need to write a plugin that exports data both in CSV and XLSX formats. October CMS

Tags: export-to-excel, xlsx, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I need to write a plugin that exports data **both in CSV and XLSX* formats**.
As a base I follow [Vojta's plugin code (1)](https://github.com/vojtasvoboda/oc-userimportexport-plugin) that uses ImportExport backend behavior.

The main plugin controller `DataImportExport` inherits a import-export Behavior from the Backend that is located in the `ImportExportController`.

```
class DataImportExport extends Controller
   {​​​​​​​
      public$implement = [
            'Backend.Behaviors.ImportExportController', 
      ];
       ...
   }
```

It's that Behavior that has methods to export data into CSV file. Yet, if I want to export into XLSX file I am supposed to add corresponding methods into that behavior, namely into the exporting controller by overriding some of its existing methods. Yet, as I do that inside `DataImportExport` controller, it does not work... as I try/test the export process remains the same as it was prior to that with only CSV...
One seems **to be not able to override/extend the backend behavior**, namely `modules\backend\behaviors\ImportExportController.php`.

For example, at the `DataimportExport` controller I try to override the `exportFromList()` method of `ImportExportController` behavior by adding code for the XLSX export -
Yet, no positive change... as I try it.

```
class DataImportExport extends Controller
{
    public $implement = [
       'Backend.Behaviors.ImportExportController', 
    ];

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
        
    BackendMenu::setContext('RainLab.User', 'user', $this->action);
    
    // extending the ImportExportController behavior
    \Backend\Behaviors\ImportExportController::extend(function($model) {
        $model->addDynamicProperty('tagsCache', null);

        $model->addDynamicMethod('writeXLSX', function() use ($model) {
            
        });

        $model->addDynamicMethod('getTagsAttribute', function() use ($model) {
            if ($this->tagsCache) {
                return $this->tagsCache;
            } else {
                return $this->tagsCache = $model->tags()->lists('name');
            }
        });
    });


}    
...

// method to override
public function exportFromList($definition = null, $options = [])
{
    ... 
    $response = Response::make();
    if ($options['export_type'] == 'csv') {
        /*
        * Response CSV
        */        
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        $response->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
        $response->header('Content-Disposition', sprintf('%s; filename="%s"', 'attachment', $filename));
        $response->setContent((string) $csv);
    } else {
        // export into xlsx code             
    }
    
    return $response;
   }
}
```

### Note

1. Vojta's plugin exports/imports only into/from CSV files.

Comment: means it's not reaching the `exportFromList` method can you try `dd()` and check if its entering in your method

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should look at https://octobercms.com/plugin/vdomah-excel where you can import and export CSV and Excel files ? The documentation is very well, and i use it on many projects to import datas and it's working well.

best,
Lucas